# Update Table with different values depending on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

```
ProductCode         Date                       Number
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:02:47.330    5
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:02:47.770    6
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:18:05.587    7
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:13:08.993    8
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:13:09.400    9
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:31:39.497    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:12:06.140    10
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:06.720    11
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:52.957    12
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:53.360    13
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:16:49.673    30000000
```

And i was trying to update the column "Number" to have a result like this:

```
ProductCode         Date                       Number
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:02:47.330    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:02:47.770    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-18 12:18:05.587    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:13:08.993    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:13:09.400    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-18 15:31:39.497    20000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:12:06.140    30000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:06.720    30000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:52.957    30000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:14:53.360    30000000
COD666AN            2020-12-23 11:16:49.673    30000000
```

I would like to avoid the cursors, but if there is no way to avoid them doesn't matter.

Note: My table could have more "blocks" ( i call blocks the dates between the higher numbers), so for example.... 14, 15, 16, 17 , 40000000.....

Logic: As you can see the table is ordered by the column [Date] asc, so i would like to update the column [Number] with the same value of the max value of the column [Number] before the next higher value, in order to have all the values before 20000000 equal to 20000000 and before 30000000 but not before 20000000 equal to 30000000.

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Comment: What determines the initial value of the Number column?  What logic are you using to determine the difference between filler block numbers and the number you want to replace the fillers with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate on the logic.  It looks like you want a cumulative (in reverse order) min, where `number` is above a threshold:

```
select t.*,
       min(case when number > 10000 then number end) over (partition by productcode order by date desc) as imputed_number
from t;
```

You can then use this in an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             min(case when number > 10000 then number end) over (partition by productcode order by date desc) as imputed_number
      from t
     )
update toupdate
     set number = imputed_number
     where number <> imputed_number;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81ca5fe1c2301ba791d7dbcc0055eb29) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The query fails. It doesn't like the order by in the min() function.

Comment: The problem could be that im using SSMS 2019 but the server is 2008?

Comment: Your version of SSMS doesn't matter.  The problem is that Aggregate Window functions (MIN, MAX, etc) are only available in SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported.  This code works in all supported versions of the database.